# How can I set 'File access' for a folder in Ubuntu through the command line?

Tags: command-line, ubuntu-10.04, permissions, file-permissions

Sorry if I'm posting this at the wrong StackExchange site, but I thought this would fit better here rather than serverfault.  Anyway...

I'm writing a bash script that creates folders and writes to new files within that folder.  The owner of the folder in which I'm creating my folder is owned by root, and I don't want to change that.  I do want to own the folder that I'm creating and any files within it, however.

So I create the folder, and naturally I then have to chown the folder to me.  I also give everyone users rwx access to the folder using chmod.  The problem arises when I try to use the > operator to send a mysqldump to a file in that folder.  I always get 'permission denied' errors, I assume because I don't have *file* access to that folder.  Sure enough, when I navigate to that folder in Nautilus, Folder access is set to 'Create and delete files', but File access is set to '---'.

Long story short, how would I go about setting that File access through a bash command?  And if you suspect that this is not the problem, what is, and how do I solve it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: umask? Or you could try to touch, chmod, then write to the file?

Comment: I can't see any mistake in your description of what you're doing, but it's very imprecise. You should post the exact (copy-paste) sequence of commands you're running and error messages you're getting. Make sure to be clear what user is running each command. Also post the output of `ls -ld` for the directories and files involved in the proces.

Comment: Sorry for the imprecision.  I would update it with my code, but touch, chmod, write seems like an excellent solution.  I'm going to try it out now.

Comment: Yep, it worked!  Thanks so much!  If you want to put it down as an answer, I can accept it.